# PHP MySQL Search for users by mutual friends and country

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am developing a sort of social network of sorts. Today I started making a dynamic search bar with AJAX and php. In in I have a query that searches for users in a "users" table. I would like to order my search results by relevance, if you know what I mean. Like for instance if I have user with id 3, searching for John, I would like to order the results by the number of mutual friends, and possibly where the person is living. 
My tables look like this

Users

id| name | country

Friends

id|user_id|friend_id

the queries I have for the moment are

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE $keyword
```

for user searching

and

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as mutual from users where id in 
(select friend_id from friends where user_id = 3 and friend_id in 
    (select friend_id from friends where user_id = 7)
```

This for instance will return the number of mutual friends between user 3 and user 7.

How can I combine the two, in order to give more relevant search results?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You only listed one table structured, but it sounds like you want to `join` on multiple tables.

Comment: Are there more than one record for a given user in the `users` table?

Comment: One row per user with all the variables needed. The table is longer but I'm simplifying for the purpose.

Comment: @Kisaragi it was a format mistake. Now it should look proper. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Have a read about joins

Answer (score 1):

> Like for instance if I have user with id 3, searching for John, I
>   would like to order the results by the number of mutual friends

Find friends of my friends whos name contains 'john' order by number of mutual friends:

```sql
select u.*, count(f1.user_id) as num_mutual_friends
from friends f1 -- my friend
join friends f2 on f2.user_id = f1.friend_id -- friend of my friend
join users u on u.id = f2.friend_id
where f1.user_id = 3
  and u.name like '%john%'
  and u.id <> 3
group by u.id
order by num_mutual_friends desc;
```

Show users from US first:

```sql
order by (u.country = 'us') desc, num_mutual_friends desc;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/728c8a/3

Comment: I am sorry, could you please elaborate a bit more on this, because I am really new to MySQL syntax. what does f1/2 and u stand for?

Comment: "A table reference can be aliased using `tbl_name AS alias_name` or `tbl_name alias_name`" ([JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)). You always need a table alias if you join it with itself.

Comment: Thank you! As far as I understand the code, the query first looks at your friends and then shows you mutual friends. Is there a way to look for name matches first and then see how many mutuals each has with you?

Comment: The query does what you're asking.  Hopefully you've had success using it and can award the answer as correct.

Comment: If you need the solution to scale though, or look beyond 2nd-degree-connections (and return results in tenths-of-seconds), you should consider a Graph Database like Neo4J or Titan.  Both solutions make it much simpler to query and rank relationships the way you've begun to, and will also spit back responses at a rate that works better for the auto-suggest-type feature you're building.